# Amazon Git Eb Tools not deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed the help page here 
and I created my application through the eb tools command line tools. I can see the application on command line, however when I log into my AWS Management console and select the region area, and click on "elastic beanstalk" I see the welcome screen asking me to create a new application,my question is why cant I see my application on the web interface? Also the application is running on the web because when I visit the url the link is active, but I see this message "Could not find rake-10.0.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)" (which if anyone knows how to fix that would also help)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that somehow amazon changed my secret keys, and my instanced where not showing. When I updated the keys on my local machine everything began working correctly.